# Error: Cask 'visual-studio-code' is unavailable: No Cask with this name exists

Tags: terminal, homebrew, visual-studio-code

I try to download visual studio code via brew, and on https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/visual-studio-code its clearly written that the install command is

```
brew install --cask visual-studio-code
```

but when I run it, it says `Error: Cask 'visual-studio-code' is unavailable: No Cask with this name exists.`

Any suggestions?

thank you in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you try to `brew upgrade` before installing Visual Studio Code?